# Rails: model accepts nested attributes error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

After spending about 6 hours on this and looking through many similar problems on here I though I better ask before i go mad

I just can seem to get this nested_attributes to work

I just keep getting

> uninitialized constant Order::OrderLine

```
orders.rb

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :customer_id, :integer, :job_number, :net_price, :order_number, :total_price, :vat,
            :account_id, :delivery_address, :customer_name, :status, :order_lines_attributes

  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :order_lines
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_lines, allow_destroy: true
  before_save :createJobNumber

    def createJobNumber
        self.job_number = rand(1..999)
    end

    def status
        self.status == "Draft Quotation" unless self.status
    end

    def customer_name

    end

    def customer_name=(name)

    end


end
```

order_lines.rb

```
    class OrderLines < ActiveRecord::Base

        belongs_to :order
        has_many :products
        attr_accessible :account_id, :comments, :order_id, :product_id, :quatity

    end
```

Here is the view

```
<div class="row">
  <%= form_for @order do |f| %>
  <% if @order.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@order.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this order from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
      <% @order.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls required">
            <%= f.hidden_field :customer_id, :class => 'number_field', :id =>"cust_id" %>
            <%= f.autocomplete_field :customer_name, autocomplete_customer_name_customers_path, :id_element => '#cust_id', :class => 'text_field ui-autocomplete-input', :placeholder => 'Customer Name' , :update_elements => {} %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group" >
          <div class="controls" >
            <%= f.text_field :delivery_address, :class => 'address-picker-input', :placeholder =>'Delivery Address' %>
          </div>
        </div>


  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="control-group">
              <%= f.text_field :order_number, :placeholder => 'Order number' %>
          </div>
  </div>
</div> <!-- close row -->
<div class="">
  <table class="table border">
      <thead class = "silver border">
          <tr>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
            <th>Comments</th>
            <th></th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <%= f.fields_for :order_lines do |builder| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= builder.text_field :quatity, :placeholder => 'Qty' %></td>
      <td><%= builder.text_field :product_id, :placeholder => 'Product' %></td>
      <td><%= builder.text_field :rate, :placeholder => 'Rate' %></td>
      <td><%= builder.text_field :comments, :placeholder => 'Comments' %></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
    <% end %>
    </table>
  </div>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class=>'btn btn-success' %>
  </div>
  <% end %> 
    <div class="modal fade" id="new_modal">
  </div>
```

and finally the orders_controller.rb

```
class OrdersController < InheritedResources::Base

    def new
        @order = Order.new
        @order.order_lines.build

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html # show.html.erb
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails is looking for model name as singular OrderLine but your model is named as OrderLines. To solve this rename the model to singular(OrderLine).

Comment: Thanks, been looking at this for hours and that fixed it